# Using try except block in Odoo server action

Tags: odoo

I'm defining a server action in Odoo 10. Within this action I am trying to use the following code:

```py
for data in datas:
    try:
        inventory_level = int(data[context['inventory_level_column']].strip())
    except TypeError:
        continue
```

However, I receive an error:

```
ValueError: <type 'exceptions.NameError'>: "name 'TypeError' is not defined"
```

Is it not possible to catch errors within the context of an Odoo server action? Why is `TypeError` not defined?

Answer (score 1):

The code written on a server action is passed through to `safe_eval` method. There the `__builtins__` are stripped and replaced (thus the `exceptions.NameError` class is removed.

You can check this behaviour on `odoo/tools/safe_eval.py` on the definition of `safe_eval` method. See `globals_dict['__builtins__'] = _BUILTINS` where `_BUILTINS` does not contain this exception.

Answer (score 1):

**Exception** is the parent class of all exception classes, so if you want to catch exception then just specify top most parent class in except and in e you will get error message.

```py
for data in datas:
    try:
        inventory_level = int(data[context['inventory_level_column']].strip())
    except Exception ,e:
        print e
        pass
```